# Load LaTeX packages from configuration file in Asymptote

Tags: packages, asymptote

I have many Asymptote files and they all need the LaTeX package `siunitx`. One way of doing this is to include the line `usepackage("siunitx");` in every single file, but I would like to do this automatically for all asy files. I am trying to use a `config.asy` file in the same directory of those asy files. However, when I compiled with Asymptote (2.65), there is no error but there is also no png or other kind of output files produced.

My `config.asy` file:

```
import plain;
settings.autoplain=true;

settings.batchView=false;
settings.tex="pdflatex";
settings.outformat="png";
settings.render=4;
settings.embed=true;
settings.toolbar=false;
settings.command="usepackage('siunitx')";
```

My `mwe.asy` file:

```
size(50mm);
draw(Label("\SI{2}{\centi\meter}"), (0,0)--(2,2));
```

When compiled by `asy mwe.asy`, nothing is produced and also there is no error. What's wrong with my `config.asy`? or is there any other smarter way to automatically load some LaTeX packages for all the asy files?

**EDIT**
My understanding is that `config.asy` is loaded by all asy files before doing anything else, that's why I am trying to use configuration file instead of something like `import mytexpreamble.asy` in every single asy file.

Comment: If I delete the line `settings.command="usepackage('siunitx')";` in `config.asy` and add either `usepackage("siunitx");` or `texpreamble("\usepackage{siunitx}");`, it will give me a correct png file after compiling; however if I put either `usepackage("siunitx");` or `texpreamble("\usepackage{siunitx}");` together with the line `settings.command="usepackage('siunitx')";` in `config.asy`, it also produces nothing.

Comment: Yes but then I would need to put `usepackage("siunitx");` into every single asy file I have. I don't want to do this, I want to put a single line in the configuration file `config.asy` and every asy file will then load those settings. Leaving `settings.command="usepackage('siunitx')";` out in `config.asy` will give me error if I don't include `usepackage("siunitx");` in `mwe.asy`

Comment: My understanding is that the `config.asy` is loaded by all asy files before doing anything else, that's why I am trying to use configuration file instead of something like `import mytexpreamble.asy` in every single asy file.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat no worry I will just clarify a bit in my question.

Comment: `config.asy` is documented [here](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/Options.html#configuration-file). One possible explanation: perhaps the directory from which `asy` is being run is not the same as the directory containing all the `asy` files? One possible workaround: try putting `config.asy` in the (new) `.asy` directory under your home directory.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Thanks for the suggestion, I did try but also didn't work. The problem is I wrongly used `settings.command` while `settings.user` should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure, there is a better and proper way to achieve this,
but a quick-and-dirty fix is this:

copy `plain.asy` to the directory of those asy files
and insert the line

```
usepackage("siunitx");
```

at the end of it.

Actually, the code in the `plain.asy` suggests
that if there is a command specified in `settings.command`,
the `Asymptote` executes it and exits immediately after that.

You can instead use

```
settings.user="usepackage('siunitx')";
```

but in this case the command

```
usersetting();
```

must be present in the beginning of the asy file.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't aware there is an `exit();` at the end of `command`, so `settings.user` is the thing I should look for. While I see no harm in putting the `usepackage("siunitx");` in `plain.asy` (at least in this case), it seems using `usersetting();` with `settings.user` is a better practice. I guess it is designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there is a command `texpreamble` that might do what you need.

From https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/abc87704/ :

> In the file config.asy you can set
>
> ```
> autoimport="common";
> ```
>
> and, in the file common.asy, you must put:
>
> ```
> texpreamble("\newcommand{\U}{\underline}");
> ```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks! This approach has the benefit of including also the user-defined functions into a single `common.asy` file, but will need to create an extra file `common.asy`. Whether `settings.user` with `usersetting();` or `autoimport` is better seems depend on the user case.